# Setting static ip causes network hangs

Tags: ubuntu, networking, raspberry-pi, netplan

I am running into a problem after setting static IP on my linux systems (Ubuntu and Raspbian).

If i set static ip, i experience 5-10 second initial hangs when interacting with it by SSH or http **after being left inactive for a few seconds**

This does not happen when using dhcp.

ensured no conflicting ips
tried turning off power management settings
using wired lan

Comment: I think we're going to need some more information. Why is "after being left inactive..." important? Are these VMs? Does "ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no ..." help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

It was an `ntp` synchronization problem, `systemd-timesyncd` in particular - it can't sync while using static IP.

I replaced it with `chrony`, and everything seems to work smoothly now.